how do i correctly run an async function outside of another async function?
been having problems with my preloader, and someone suggested this:
async def setupPreloader():
    global preloader
    preloader = None
    preloader = await songsFind()
asyncio.run(setupPreloader())

this still doesnt work and the preloader is STILL running synchronously and waiting for the await to arrive, causing about a full second of lag while the disk is being scanned
the full code is available at here under downloads, get the bare version if you just want a running copy for testing/crossreference

The beginning of the first paragraph seems to be cut off.

What else did you expect to happen while songsFind is executed? There is nothing else that asyncio.run can do.

It seems as though what you are trying to achieve is to have the setupPreloader function start songsFind(), but not to wait for it to complete before returning.
To do this you need to create a task.
import asyncio

preloader = None

def setupPreloader():
    global preloader
    preloader = asyncio.create_task(songsFind())

async def otherFunctionRequiringLoadedSongs():        
    await preloader
    ...

async def main():
    setupPreloader()
    ...
    await otherFunctionRequiringLoadedSongs()

asyncio.run(asyncio.main())

Note that the call to create_task() and await preloader must occur within the same top-level asyncio.run() call otherwise the event loop may be different.

i cannot have my main function scope be running in a function as that would require rewriting the whole program

I've just had a look at the full code file, and it is possible to refactor the code into a main function: Move all functions definitions to the top of your file, and then encapsulate everything else into a function. However this won't actually help as your songsFind has no actual asynchronous code in it (no await keywords). I suggest you look at threads (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) instead of async. Python does not provide async filesystem access APIs
